# h-ref link in error message is not working in lightining

Tags: lightning

There is already an account/accounts existing in the system similar to the one you are trying to create or edit. Please

```
<a href="/apex/SurvivorshipRulesGenericTriggerHistory?key=cok&object=Account target="_self"">
 - click here    
</a>
```

to see the details and initiate merge process.However, if you still want to create/update the record please select the Allow Duplicates checkbox field and continue to save the record. Above is error mesg coming from trigger,in classic,click link is working fine,in lightining is not working,need help,thanks in advance

Comment: In lightning you have to implement that logic manually, it is different that in regular visualforce. You cannot load visualforce page in lightning.

Comment: i even dont know how to start?!..if you know anything,pls share with me

Comment: I think the easiest would be trailhead https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/lex_dev_lc_basics